# PS3 glitches when playing certain games, could this be a sign of it dying

Tags: ps3

My PS3 glitches when playing certain games.

It works fine until I play a game like Ski doo snowmobile challenge. I load it up and sometimes it just wants to got to the left of the menu, when I try and enter a race or go into free roam, my character jumps up and turns to the left. I already checked that the controller glitches, I also have a PS3 slim and the controller works fine on that. I also tried multiple controllers on the glitchy PS3 and still does the same. I even tried the game on my PS3 slim(disc btw) and it works perfectly.

All I want to know is if it’s a sign of the PS3 coming to its due date. And if anyone has experienced this with any PS3’s they own.

And the glitchy PS3 is I believe a 60GB model(not sure exactly) and has been in the family since at least 2008 or 2009.